# DQN's Q-loss converaged but it performed poorly

Tags: python, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning, dqn

I am trying to code my own DQN in Python, using pytorch. I am trying it on the CartPole environment.

Although the Q-loss converaged, the model performed poorly.

Replay buffer was also used in the model with a size of 2000 and the double networks were also used.I updated the target network when the q_net network was updated 100 times.(ps: q_net was used to decide which action to choose.)

I tried to use different network architectures and different combinations of hyper-parameters, but the model still performed poorly, which just kept swaying and never kept itself balanced.

Appreciate for your help, sincerely!!

Here is the figure of Q-loss result:

[Q-loss figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNb55.png)

[a closer look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bnSK5.png)

Here is the code for action taking.

```
    def take_action(self,state):
 
    
    if self.learn_count<=10:
        self.eposilon = 0.1
    else:
        self.eposilon = 0.9
    
    decision = np.random.choice([0,1],p = [1-self.eposilon,self.eposilon])
    
    if decision == 1:    
        #final_decision = self.q_net(state.cuda().detach()).argmax()
        final_decision = self.q_net(torch.Tensor(state).to(self.device))
        final_decision = torch.max(final_decision, 0)[1].data.numpy()
    else:
        final_decision = np.random.choice([i for i in range(self.action_space)])

    return final_decision.item()
```

Here is the code for training the network.

```
    def update_nn(self):
    
        if self.learn_count%100 ==0:
            self.synchronous_NN()
        for i in range(self.num_epoches):
            self.learn_count = self.learn_count+1
            self.training_nn()
    
        return None
    def training_nn(self):
    
    index = random.sample(range(self.replay_buffer.shape[0]),self.minibatch_size)
    
    chosen_sample = self.replay_buffer[index,:]
    
    last_state = copy.deepcopy(chosen_sample[np.isnan(chosen_sample[:,-1:]).squeeze(),:])
    not_last_state = copy.deepcopy(chosen_sample[~np.isnan(chosen_sample[:,-1:]).squeeze(),:])
    
    input_not_last_state = torch.FloatTensor(not_last_state[:,:4]).to(self.device)
    action_index = torch.LongTensor(not_last_state[:,4].reshape(-1,1)).to(self.device)
    action_value = self.q_net(input_not_last_state).gather(1,action_index)
    max_action_value = not_last_state[:,5]+self.gamma*self.fixed_q_net(input_not_last_state).detach().max(1).values.numpy()
    
    last_state = np.nan_to_num(last_state)
    input_last_state = torch.FloatTensor(last_state[:,:4]).to(self.device)
    last_action_index = torch.LongTensor(last_state[:,4].reshape(-1,1)).to(self.device)
    last_action_value = self.q_net(input_last_state).gather(1,last_action_index)
    last_max_action_value = last_state[:,5]
    
    X = torch.cat([action_value,last_action_value])
    y = torch.FloatTensor(np.hstack([max_action_value,last_max_action_value]).reshape(-1,1)).detach()
        
    loss = self.loss(X, y)

    self.optimizer.zero_grad() # reset the gradient to zero
    loss.backward()
    self.optimizer.step() # execute back propagation for one step
    
    self.loss_curve.append(loss)
    
    return None
```

here is the part of playing:

```
    def start_to_play(self):
    
    agent = Agent()
    agent.initial_Q_network(2)
    agent.initial_replay_buffer()
    
    self.env = gym.make('CartPole-v0')
    self.env = self.env.unwrapped
    
    for i in range(self.episode):
        if i%50 ==1:
            agent.save_model(i)
        
        step = 0

        state = self.env.reset()
        ep_r = 0
        
        while(True):
            
            action = agent.take_action(state)
            observation, reward, done, info = self.env.step(action)
            self.env.render()
            #next_state = self.capture_state()
            next_state = observation
            

            x, x_dot, theta, theta_dot = observation
            r1 = (self.env.x_threshold - abs(x)) / self.env.x_threshold - 0.8
            r2 = (self.env.theta_threshold_radians - abs(theta)) / self.env.theta_threshold_radians - 0.5
            reward = r1 + r2

            ep_r = reward+ep_r 
            
            if done:
                reward = reward-20
                state1_np = np.array(state)
                state2_np = np.array([np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan])
                agent.add_replay_buffer(np.hstack([state1_np,np.array([action,reward]),state2_np]))
                if agent.replay_buffer.shape[0]>300:
                    agent.update_nn()
                    print(i,step,round(ep_r, 2))
                break
            else:
                state1_np = np.array(state)
                state2_np = np.array(next_state)
                agent.add_replay_buffer(np.hstack([state1_np,np.array([action,reward]),state2_np]))

                if agent.replay_buffer.shape[0]>300:
                    agent.update_nn()
                    
            
            state = next_state
            step = step+1
    self.plot_curve(agent)
        
            
    return None
```

Thanks for your time!!

Answer (score 0):

Loss in reinforcement learning is not very important. In fact, you could see very good agents with good performances but bad results in term of neural network losses.

I suggest you to look into other implementations hyperparameters, since CartPole has been solved an infinite amount of times with multiple algorithms.

The first thing that might be wrong is the experience replay buffer, which is too small. But then again, look into other DQN implementation for CartPole and try to use the same hyperparameters that they are using